How can I get the position of register address in csapp lab2
0x000000000000128d <+0>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
0x0000000000001291 <+4>:     mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
0x000000000000129a <+13>:    mov    %rax,0x8(%rsp)
0x000000000000129f <+18>:    xor    %eax,%eax
0x00000000000012a1 <+20>:    lea    0x4(%rsp),%rcx
0x00000000000012a6 <+25>:    mov    %rsp,%rdx
0x00000000000012a9 <+28>:    lea    0x1a05(%rip),%rsi        # 0x2cb5
0x00000000000012b0 <+35>:    callq  0xee0 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x00000000000012b5 <+40>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
0x00000000000012b8 <+43>:    jle    0x12d7 <phase_3+74>
0x00000000000012ba <+45>:    cmpl   $0x7,(%rsp)
0x00000000000012be <+49>:    ja     0x135d <phase_3+208>
0x00000000000012c4 <+55>:    mov    (%rsp),%eax
0x00000000000012c7 <+58>:    lea    0x1772(%rip),%rdx        # 0x2a40
0x00000000000012ce <+65>:    movslq (%rdx,%rax,4),%rax
0x00000000000012d2 <+69>:    add    %rdx,%rax
0x00000000000012d5 <+72>:    jmpq   *%rax

If I want to know %rax's position, what should I do?
And also I find that %rdx = 0x2a40, according to the last four lines calculations, I could get the answer 0x5480, however if I use gdb, there is no value there which really confuses me.
Thanks a lot for helping me.
Please describe the solution to the problem which I encounter with.
Thanks.

You are looking at offsets not addresses. You should have no problem examining registers or memory at runtime in gdb, For example you can do x/8d $rdx when stopped at line +65
